Since upgrading pandas I can no longer insert a row without a Future Warning. How to fix?
I have a dataframe with a well populated column of datetimes called "ds". My intention is to insert one row before the others:
start = df_p['ds'].iloc[0] - pd.Timedelta(1,"d")
if start not in df_p.index:
    df_p.loc[start] = np.NaN

What I get is:

FutureWarning: The behavior of DataFrame concatenation with empty or all-NA entries is deprecated. In a future version, this will no longer exclude empty or all-NA columns when determining the result dtypes. To retain the old behavior, exclude the relevant entries before the concat operation.

Obviously I am missing something dumb, but I can't see it...

See this.

It is because of dtype mismatch with nans, try:
start = df_p['ds'].iloc[0] - pd.Timedelta(1,"d")
if start not in df_p.index:
    df_p = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(index=[start], values=np.nan, columns=df_p.columns).astype(df_p.dtypes), df_p], ignore_index=True)

